Denoising data with Rayleigh distribution assumption
Assume I have 3 random variables, $X$ (matrix of pixels of the noised images),$Y$ (matrix of pixels of the denoised unknown image),$Z$ (matrix of pixels of a noise with Rayleigh distribution), related by $$X=Y.Z$$
In practice, $X$ data is known, collected thanks to a specific censor. The censor has Rayleigh noise characteristics, represented by $Z$. The mean and the variance of $Z$, are known, and for the sake of simplicity, assume that $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$. Also, the pixel distributions are independant from each other and all follow the same distribution.
In the hypothesis of $Z$ being a gaussian noise, the simplest way to proceed to estimate $Y$, is as follow: derive an order $1$ approximation $((X -\mu_X)(Z-\mu_Z)$ is negligible)
$$
Z = \mu_Z.X + \mu_X(Z-\mu_Z)
$$
where $\mu_*$ stands for the mean of the variable and then, under normality condition, we can derive a formula to estimate $Y$ with standard linear regression.
In the hypothesis where $Z$ has a Rayleigh distribution, what is the best way to estimate $Y$ ?

The Rayleigh deals with one of the obvious problems with the assumptions in your earlier post, but not several others (some of which I pointed out). This is in effect a new XY problem.
